# Minimization boundary value problem, using the first variation

Tags: optimization, boundary-value-problem

> Consider the minimization problem $$min\{ \int_{-1}^1 [\frac{1}{2} (u'')^2-fu]
> > dx| u(-1)=u(1)=u'(1)=u'(-1)=0\}$$ Determine the solution of the
>   boundary value problem which results from the necessary conditions for
>   a minimum if $f$ is constant.

So first lets determine the boundary value problem, I thought that a necessary condition was that the first variation is $0$ for a minimum. This would lead too

$$\frac{d}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0} \int_{-1}^1 [\frac{1}{2} (u''+\epsilon\varphi'')^2-fu-f\epsilon \varphi] dx = 0$$
With $u(-1)=u(1)=u'(1)=u'(-1)=0$

Which led me too  $$\int_{-1}^1 (u''\varphi''-fu)dx = 0$$

I tried to solve this with the product rule for integration but that did not really help me.

Did I get the boundary value problem right? If so, how do I proceed? If not, how do I find the right one?

Comment: Is $u\in C^4([-1,1])$?

Comment: @Serdar I don't know, this is everything I have